# Typescript, generic variadic factory function returning tuple

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

In typescript, a factory function can be created like this, with a return type defined:

```
function factory1<T>(object: new () => T): T {
  return new object();
}
```

If I want to create several different objects, I can extend this function to:

```
function factory2<T, U>(object1: new () => T, object2: new () => U): [T, U] {
  return [new object1(), new object2()];
}
```

Now to my question: Can this factory pattern be generalized to take any number of unrelated object types and still return a typed tuple? Or is the only option to drop the strong typing and revert to using any?

Something like this:

```
function factory3<T extends any[]>(...objects: {new(): any}[]): [...T] {
  // BODY
}
```

The issue with the last one, factory3, is that we lose the type of T and instead get "typeof T". For example:

```
    factory3(ClassA, ClassB, ClassC);

// actually becomes this:

    factory3<typeof ClassA, typeof ClassB, typeof ClassC>(...) : [typeof ClassA, typeof ClassB, typeof ClassC] {}

// But we want this to happen instead, which is possible for factory 1:

    factory3<typeof ClassA, typeof ClassB, typeof ClassC>(...) : [ClassA, ClassB, ClassC] {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can make the factory rest argument a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  You'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or something like it to convince the compiler that the returned value in the body is really a `[...T]`:

```
function factory<T extends any[]>(...ctors: { [K in keyof T]: new () => T[K] }) {
    return ctors.map(x => new x) as [...T];
}
```

You can verify that this works:

```
class A {
    x = 1;
}
class B {
    u = "u";
}
class C {
    s = true;
}

const objects = factory(A, B, C);
// const objects: [A, B, C]
console.log(JSON.stringify(objects)); // [{"x":1},{"u":"u"},{"s":true}]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAhtOAnAngHgCqICmAHlIWACYDOiKYWA2gLoB8AFAHRfoZUBciAN6IGAaUQwkAa0JY4wRHiYCwhAO6I2ASkQBeForFNEAXx2CAUImuIMhKCAxIeVDgFsUABzbE9B1RrEOig0DFwcSgDcFiYWFhAANiE0AIJCVja+uogAjNGxicmIAELpNoggeogARCDVkYgx8UlUNADCZTY02VAYIIT5cRAIVFCIcABGAFaE0N3IaFCYWGwpADQlG21a0QD0u4jDYKPj07NQ-CLrm4htTPEjcAmEHAlwAOZsAFIAygDyADkOKMMJJ3jBgCtJjM5lodoh9iJBNViNU+DkTGtkXU+LVqpjkVQ0b1+iZjBYgA)